# jquery variable in php echo

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this jquery script (slider):

```
<script>
$( function() {
    $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
        range: "max",
        min: 1,
        max: 25,
        value: 1,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#amount").val(ui.value);
        }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( $("#slider-range-max").slider("value") );
});
</script>
```

This is my html outout:

```
 <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">

 <div id="slider-range-max"></div>
```

I want the value of my slider stored as a php variable.

Comment: do you want to send the value of the slider to your php code ? your question is not clear ?!

Comment: yes thats what i want to do

Comment: is your html slider and php code on the same file ?

Comment: yes both are in the same file

Comment: well the thing is, you need to separate your html code from your php code, then from your html (javascript code) make an ajax request to the php code (which is in a different file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call upon a php code that might have some logic in it, you need to have your html and javascript in a file, then your php code in a different file, like so :

**html_file.php** (contains only html template and javascript).

html part:

```
<input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
<div id="slider-range-max"></div>
```

Javascript part:

```
<script>
    $( function() {
        $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
            range: "max",
            min: 1,
            max: 25,
            value: 1,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
            },
            change: function(event, ui) {
                $.post('php_file.php', {slider_val: ui.value}).done(
                    function(result) {
                      //your php code sends result back here.
                      //do something with result.
                      console.log(result);
                    }
                );
            }
        });
        $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ) );
    });
</script>
```

**php_file.php** (contains the php code and logic).

you then retrieve the value in your php code like so:

```
<?php

//$slider_val contains the value of your slider
$slider_val = $_POST['slider_val'];

//you can output the value back to your javascript like so
echo $slider_val;
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your help. Just to understand it. If I chose in my slider a number this value will be transfered and echo out in the php_file.php? At the Moment I have  blank php_file.php. Is there a Little mistake or do I missunderstand it?

Comment: copy the php code i provided in my answer to your php_file.php, and try that, P.S: yes your slider value will be transferred to your php_file.php then you can use it however you want.

Comment: Yeah I did this. But I just receive a blank php_file.php page. It seems that the transfer of the value doesn´t work.

Comment: html_file.php and php_file.php should be on the same folder.

Comment: open your browser's developer console. then see if the value of your slider is displayed when you change the slider value.

Comment: I can´t see the value in the tool. Here is a screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/ebrWmvF   (from the html_file.php)

Comment: actually that's the Elements Tab, check The Console tab ok :)

Comment: Now I see the output it in the console, sorry. https://imgur.com/a/GcEqASz

Comment: glad it works :), if this answers your question please make this your accepted answer, if you need help come back again, have a nice day :)

Comment: Thank you. Just one last question. I want to php echo out now the value with php on my html_file.php. Is this possible? Something like <?php echo($slider_val);?>; Since I have the results now in the console. I need to use them in a normal php script.

Comment: i'm not sure in understand what you mean, but if you are going to change the value of an html element after you've done something with the slider value then you can use javascript to do that, `$('#your_output_id').html(result);`

Comment: I want to echo out the $slider_val in a link:
<?php
echo '<img src="http://example.com/',$slider_val, '.jpg">';
 ?>

Comment: ok now i get what you mean, you want to dynamically display images depending the the slider's value, right ?

Comment: yeah that was what I needed. sorry that it wasn´t clear.

Comment: i thought you were going to use the slider's value to do some database related queries, or something like that. i suppose you only need javasccript to change your image src attribute `<img id="my_img">` then in your slider's change event handler update the src attribute `$('#my_img').attr('src', 'http://example.com/' + ui.value + '.jpg')`;

Answer (score 0):

You can send the input value to php like this

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Amount" onkeyup="send(this.value)">
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script>
function send(str) {

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "send.php?value=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();

}
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
    $value = $_REQUEST["value"];
echo $value;
```

Try this. Hope it helps to solve your problem.